# Accidentally saved the source html instead of original html

Tags: html, url, web-scraping

I am trying to extract/scrape specific information from a website I was subscribed to. I had to work locally since I was collaborating with another researcher. So, I downloaded the html file by using chrome and "view source code" (CTRL+U), and then "save as" (CTRL + S) to read the file with lxml or bs4 to extract the information we wanted to work with. However, the current online html file on chrome is different than my saved file. I can only show the html partially because it contains private information.

Chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Contact Report for XXXX </title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
<meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

HTML File I am reading is like this:

```
<!doctype html> 
<!-- saved from url=(0227)https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body><div class="line-gutter-backdrop"></div><table><tbody><tr><td class="line-number" value="1"></td><td class="line-content"><br></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="2"></td><td class="line-content"><br></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="3"></td><td class="line-content"><br></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="4"></td><td class="line-content"><br></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="5"></td><td class="line-content"><span class="html-doctype">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="6"></td><td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;html <span class="html-attribute-name">lang</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">en</span>"&gt;
```

After some research on Stackoverflow, I realized that we had to save the html directly instead of saving the html source file. But, we cannot save it again because 1. we saved around a 1000 this way, 2. we paid for the service and can't pay again.

Is there a way to revert the second html file to a parseable version? Otherwise, I'll try a regular expression approach.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take the time to edit your Q so you 2nd section is not a mile wide. If you expect us to look at your data, you should present it in a format that is easily read. ALSO,I think you'll get your quickest result just to focus on extracting the info you need from the 2nd version of your HTML. Finally, it's not clear what you mean by **I realized that we had to save the html directly instead of saving the html file**. Please include a link to those Q/As researched on StackOverflow. I"ve never heard of this. Isn't HTML = html = htm = ... etc, etc? Good luck.

Comment: The two sets of HTML you provide are **completely** different. You can't convert from one to the other based on the information you've got there.

Comment: @shelter 2nd section being a mile is also part of the question. I edited the part in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`


`soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')  # use html5lib parser (pip install html5lib)
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.prettify(), 'html5lib')  # repair structure with prettify()
soup.table  # Probably is what you need`

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Why it was downvoted, instead of just read the question and try to help a man.
Don't you see that he was manually store html?

Comment: Thanks @Галичанський Роман. Unfortunately, it is still not parseable.

Comment: Sure, @azube. Can you show how you trying to parse it? And what is expected output?